# D3: How to have multiple graphs on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am very new to programming.
I am posting the link to my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9izFLi6Ft2mayadNyC4u

There are 2 graphs here i.e. "SJF", "FCFS" which are generated on clicking their respective buttons.
The problem here is:

Clicking these buttons displays corresponding rectangles but they do not appear one below the other as I would like.
(This could be because the div code block is "inline").

```
div.bar {
                display: inline-block;
}
```

I have no idea how to proceed. I tried removing inline but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have no idea what the result should look like, but have you tried changing *inline-block* to *block*?

Comment: i removed the display:inline-block and it gives  desired result, http://plnkr.co/edit/HnYY0ewchz3bZUtfgkpd?p=info is this  desired output http://www.clipular.com/c/6001714717523968.png?k=rPl0o3TdKvH8qyB043vPZYIbItA

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ox4IJNXMGIbnJFaVRBcThrOHc/view?usp=sharing 
it should look like this.
one graph below the other but the blocks in a graph have to be inline.
currently the graphs are one below the other but not aligned to each other.
i am looking to align them so they don't look weird.